# Reactjs Sibling Component not getting the updated state value

Tags: reactjs

1) How do I pass this value as a prop to Child1 Component 
2) If I just pass the state value to Child1 component I am not getting the updated value within Child1 -

Followed different articles - about passing props between siblings but nothing works..
Parent:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggledata: '',
    };
  }

   handleToggle(value) { //getting the updated value to 'value'
    this.setState({ toggledata: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child1 ToggleStatus={this.state.toggledata} />
        <Child2 callbackFromParent={this.handleToggle.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Parent.propTypes = {
  params: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Child2:

```
class Child1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({ text: 'green' }, () => {
      this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.text);
    });
  }

render(){
return (
          <a onClick={() => { this.handleClick(event) }} href="">
            Click me
          </a>

    );
  }
}
export default Child1;
```

Comment: You should be getting an error with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You were not binding `this` to your callback.
You're `this.setState` is not called for your parent, it is called within `Child2`. The context of `this` in `handleToggle` is from Child2, not the Parent if you don't bind it.

`<Child2 callbackFromParent={this.handleToggle.bind(this)} />`

Comment: then how to call this.setState for the click happening in Child2 and register it in the parent component and pass it to Child1 - that is my actual question - may be I did not put it right and I have updated with bind..